# Getting error while using operator overloading << in c++ using friend function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making a class for polynomial. I am getting error in operator overloading. I am using it first time, so the error might be silly 
`get_size()` is returning max length of array.
    `coefficient[]` is array for coeff.
    `exponant[]` is for exponent 
I have declared them using reference
`int* coefficient;
     int* exponent;`

Polynomial.h

```
 friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&,Polynomial&);
```

Polynomial.cpp

```
//overloading << operator
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out,Polynomial& obj)
{
for (int i=0 ; i < obj.get_size() ; i++)
 {
     if(obj.coefficient[i]!=0)
     {
         if (i== obj.get_size()-1)      //last term does not have '+'
             out << obj.coefficient[i] << "x^" << obj.exponent[i] <<endl;
         else 
             std::ostream& i = out << obj.coefficient[i] << "x^" <<  obj.exponent[i] << " + ";
     }
 }
 return out;
 }
```

main.cpp

```
    cout << pol    // where pol is object
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you're not showing us the entire code, what error message are you getting?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Compiler error? Run time error?

Comment: Should be `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Polynomial& obj)` BTW.

Comment: I have putted semi colon after pol; in main.

Comment: Ummm the normal way of thinking would be asking yourself and checking why "`get_size()` is returning max length of array". Did you do that? Or I misunderstood what the problem is... BTW, does it even compile? There seem to be more than one problem with this code.

Comment: You'll want `const Polynomial&` for the parameter. It's a good idea in any case; and will fix any errors you might have trying to call `const` member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what the error is, this is definitely not correct:

```
std::ostream& i = out << obj.coefficient[i] << "x^" <<  obj.exponent[i] << " + ";
```

Should be:

```
out << obj.coefficient[i] << "x^" <<  obj.exponent[i] << " + ";
```